# How to use wildcards at the beginning of property value?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, wildcard

i need something like that...

```
match (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP]-(NODE) where NODE.name=~ "*.(?i)something.*"  Return n.name
```

The wildcard at the end is working. But the other won't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, just put the case insensitive marker at the beginning and use `.*` as placeholder. Try the following:

```
match (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP]-(NODE) where NODE.name=~ "(?i).*something.*"  Return n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This works: 
     match (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP]-(NODE) where NODE.name=~ ".*(?i).something.*"  Return n.name